# Exporting Jtable into the Excelsheet using HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, swing, export, poi-hssf

Hello I am trying to Export Jtable Data into the Excel Sheet using HSSFWorkbook. and i am getting all the content what Table have but i am not getting Table Headers please can anyone help for the same.

Here the Command used for Taking content of the Jtable.

```
        try {
                    HSSFWorkbook fWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                    HSSFSheet fSheet = fWorkbook.createSheet("new Sheet");
                    HSSFFont sheetTitleFont = fWorkbook.createFont();
                    File file = new File("/home/kishan/NetBeansProjects/JavaChecking/src/com/verve/SwingChecking/book.xls");
                    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = fWorkbook.createCellStyle();

                    sheetTitleFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                    //sheetTitleFont.setColor();
                    TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();


                    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        HSSFRow fRow = fSheet.createRow((short) i);
                        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            HSSFCell cell = fRow.createCell((short) j);
                            cell.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

                        }

                    }
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                fWorkbook.write(bos);
                bos.close();
                fileOutputStream.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

        }



for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                HSSFRow fRow = fSheet.createRow((short) i);
                for(int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    HSSFCell cell = fRow.createCell((short) j);
                    cell.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());

                    System.out.println(model.getColumnName(j));
                }
            }
```

last for loop is not addind data of table header.[image]

and i am getting this excel file

[image]
how to get Table header along with that??

Comment: get the JTableHeader from XxxTbaleModel/JTable, depends of source for you export ...., be sure that question in this form isn't answerable on SO

Comment: have to (little bit) bothering with offical Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables

Comment: ya last for loop that is what i have tried for the getting Tableheader. and i have attach screenshot to get clear that.

Comment: here are a few Q&A how to export JTable to File, logisc is similair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this to add Column Names in the first row of your sheet:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = jTable1.getColumnModel();
HSSFRow fRow = fSheet.createRow((short) 0);

for(int j = 0; j < tcm.getColumnCount(); j++) {

   HSSFCell cell = fRow.createCell((short) j);
   cell.setCellValue(tcm.getColumn(j).getHeaderValue().toString());           

}
```

You could run this first and then add the table data starting from the second row.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my implementation of the HSSF Workbook from the answers in this thread.

I created a class `ExcelWriter` then a Method Writer which takes two parameters; the `JTable` and the `FileLocation` to be used.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author oluwajayi
 */
public class ExcelWriter {

    public static void Writer (JTable jTable1, String Location) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

                HSSFWorkbook fWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet fSheet = fWorkbook.createSheet("new Sheet");
                HSSFFont sheetTitleFont = fWorkbook.createFont();
                HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = fWorkbook.createCellStyle();
                sheetTitleFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                //sheetTitleFont.setColor();
                TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();

                //Get Header
                TableColumnModel tcm = jTable1.getColumnModel();
                HSSFRow hRow = fSheet.createRow((short) 0);
                for(int j = 0; j < tcm.getColumnCount(); j++) {                       
                   HSSFCell cell = hRow.createCell((short) j);
            cell.setCellValue(tcm.getColumn(j).getHeaderValue().toString());
                   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                }

                //Get Other details
                for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    HSSFRow fRow = fSheet.createRow((short) i+1);
                    for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                        HSSFCell cell = fRow.createCell((short) j);
                        cell.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                    }
                }
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Location);
    try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {
        fWorkbook.write(bos);
    }
            fileOutputStream.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are only writing the data in the `TableModel` to the workbook. This model does not contain the table header. Take a look at [JTable.getTableHeader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getTableHeader%28%29)

for example:

```
public class JTableExport {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] columnNames = new Object[] {"column1", "column2"};
    JTable table = new JTable(new Object[0][0], columnNames);
    TableColumnModel model = table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(model.getColumn(i).getHeaderValue());
    }
}
}
```

this code prints

```
column1
column2
```

Comment: I am just trying that. and can u just update small code for that?

Comment: I added the example code. Instead of `System.out.println(..)` you need to create new `HSSFCell`s and add them to your workbook

Comment: ya i am getting now that table header but not able to add into the excel sheet :( but ya +1 for suggestion.

Comment: If you add the table header to your workbook before you add the content of the model you need to mind that your second for-loop starts with `for(int i = 1; ...` because otherwise the table header will be overwritten!

Comment: if u can not give simple sample then no need of your suggestion too. thanks for spending time for this.

Answer (score 0):

for(int j = 0; j < tcm.getColumnCount(); j++) {

HSSFCell cell = fRow.createCell((short) j);
   cell.setCellValue(tcm.getColumn(j).getHeaderValue().toString());

}

for(int j = 0; j < tcm.getRowCount(); j++) {

HSSFCell cell = fRow.createCell((short) j);
   cell.setCellValue(tcm.getColumn(j).getHeaderValue().toString());

}

Answer (score 0):

I created this code:

```
public void Export() {

    JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser();
    save.setDialogTitle("Save as...");
    save.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("xls", "xlsx", "xlsm"));
    int choose = save.showSaveDialog(null);

    if(choose == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        XSSFWorkbook export = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = export.createSheet("new file");
        try{
            TableModel tableModel = showQuery.getModel();

            for(int i=0; i<tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
                XSSFRow newRow = sheet1.createRow(i);
                for(int j=0; j<tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell((short) j);
                    if(i==0){
                        XSSFCellStyle style = export.createCellStyle();
                        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex());
                        style.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                        style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
                        style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
                        style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
                        style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
                        newCell.setCellStyle(style);
                        newCell.setCellValue(tableModel.getColumnName(j));
                    } else {
                        XSSFCellStyle style = export.createCellStyle();
                        style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
                        style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
                        style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
                        style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
                        newCell.setCellStyle(style);
                    newCell.setCellValue(tableModel.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            FileOutputStream otp = new FileOutputStream(save.getSelectedFile()+".xlsx");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(otp);
            export.write(bos);
            bos.close();
            otp.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arquivo exprtado com sucesso!");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```